# How to omit the option value in a form:option tag?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, taglib

How can I add a label in the first line of a dropdown list without using a Value=""?

When I create a dropdown list without inserting a title in the first line of my form, the jsp and the select work fine:

```
<form:select id="idStatusUpdate" path="topic.id_topic" class="form-control" 
                        items="${topiclist}" itemLabel="ntopic" itemValue="id_topic" >
</form:select>
```

but when I try to insert a label for presentation it gives me the following error, since the option value is not defined.

```
<form:select id="idStatusUpdate" path="topic.id_topic" class="form-control">
    <form:option value="" label="Seleccionar Tema" />
    <form:options items="${topiclist}" itemLabel="ntopic" itemValue="id_topic"></form:options>
</form:select>
```

With this log:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot be assigned to a primitive type**

** Thanks for your help**

Comment: What is unclear in "A null value cannot be assigned to a primitive type"?

Comment: What is unclear about not understanding a message when you are not a programmer and when you ask for help? It shows no mistake in the first case and I do not see the difference with the form:option value="" label="Seleccionar Tema" or anything related with a null value. I do not see the problem that's why I ask. Sorry to bother you. Happy saturday

Comment: It's a question. What is unclear? null value? primitive type? assigned? If you're using Java, spring-mvc, jsps, you *are* de facto a programmer.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not feel like one. I just trying to learn. When you are not one you think different. You have something that works and the you modify it (form:option value="" label="Seleccionar Tema") and it stops working, but when the reason has nothing to do with the difference, you google and ask for help.

Comment: No. You start by reading the error message, try to understand what it means, and think why the change you made leads to such an error being thrown. You never submitted a null value before, since there was no way to do it. It's now possible. And you're trying to store this null value in id_topic. id_topic has a primitive type. Primitive types can't be assigned to null. It's all about logic and reading the error.

Comment: I do read the error message. That is why I pasted it in the question. BUT I supposed that it was Spring error, not at the JSP. When I was in bed I thought it could be alerting about the value of the initial option and this morning I see you message. I have been looking and I can not find how to omit the value part and it gives me an error if omited. THANKS for you patience. Sometimes is better to go to bed before you start to suppose wrong things and give it a fresh look in the morning.